# Uncaught (in promise) Passed component - undefined is invalid. kendoui

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, vue-composition-api

In this example https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/ there is a computed method

```
gridSearchMessage() {
      return provideLocalizationService(this).toLanguageString(
        "gridSearch",
        "Search in all columns..."
      );
}
```

this is OptionsAPI. So I wanted to convert it to CompositionAPI

```
const gridSearchMessage : ComputedRef<string> = computed<string>(() => {
      return provideLocalizationService(this).toLanguageString(
        "gridSearch",
        "Search in all columns..."
      )
    })
```

but then I'm getting the error above. Any explanation why this happens? By just changing this method to

```
const gridSearchMessage : ComputedRef<string> = computed<string>(() => {
      return "Search in all columns..."
    })
```

all works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` which refers to the component instance is available in the `Options API` only.

For the Composition API, you need to get `getCurrentInstance` function from `vue` Module.

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
const instance = getCurrentInstance()
const gridSearchMessage : ComputedRef<string> = computed<string>(() => {
      return provideLocalizationService(instance).toLanguageString(
        "gridSearch",
        "Search in all columns..."
      )
    })
```